# WCF - Http and https on SOAP and REST

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, soap

I have a site that needs to be able to create a http and https connection. I have IIS setup so that it accepts https on both SOAP and REST requests, this works.

My problem is that customers that do not have https can use my site. If they don't have it I delete the site binding for https:

[image]
After I do this I get the following exception when accessing the site: 'Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding'

My web.config looks like this:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
 <bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttpBinding" messageEncoding="Text">
    </binding>

    <binding name="basicHttpsBinding" messageEncoding="Text">
      <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>

  </basicHttpBinding>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpBinding">
    </binding>

    <binding name="webHttpsBinding">       
      <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<services>
  <service name="XXX.XXX">
    <endpoint address="rest" behaviorConfiguration="RestBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="webHttpBinding" contract="XXX.IXXX">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>

    <endpoint address="rest" behaviorConfiguration="RestBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="webHttpsBinding" contract="XXX.IXXX">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>

    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="XXXBehavior" binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBinding" contract="XXX.IXXX">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>

    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="XXXBehavior" binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="basicHttpsBinding"  contract="XXX.IXXX">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>

    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="Mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="XXXBehavior">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>

    <behavior name="RestBehavior">
      <webHttp helpEnabled="true" defaultBodyStyle="Bare"  defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json"
               automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false" faultExceptionEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean "customers that do not have https"?

Comment: @GlenThomas The application I'm developing can be installed on different servers, some of the customers do not have a https certificate to use.

Comment: I see. They could use a self signed certificate. If the application has a need for a secure connection then its better than nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a binding configuration with transport security (`security mode="Transport"`), but then you configure IIS not to support it.

If you remove HTTPS from IIS, then you must remove your HTTPS endpoints from web.config.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know if it is possible to configure my web.config in a way so that I can keep the current settings but disable the basicHttpsBinding when IIS does not allow https?

Comment: You can generate the endpoints in code rather than specifying them in the web.config. That is probably the best solution.